# Send variables to Web API method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have set up a basic MVC web API project with the following method in the ValuesController class -

```
// GET api/values/5
public string Get(int id)
{
    return "Success!";
}
```

And calling this in the client like -

```
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:12345/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/values/5");
 if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
 {
     result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 }
```

I am relatively new t MVC however I am trying to modify this method to accept string variable to be used in a database call. For instance something like -

```
// GET api/values/number/house/street
public string Get(string no, string house, string street)
{
    // use variables
    return "Success!";
}
```

Then the client something like -

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/values/" + no + house + street);
 if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
 {
     result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 }
```

I am essentially trying to use the API as a webservice however unsure how to modify it to work in such a way.

When I tried the above code it returned `Bad Request`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably haven't setup the routing to your WebApi service. 
Check out this resource on how to set it up: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions

EDIT:
Or, wait! If may be that the call to your service is wrong. If you look at your api method definition the comment tells you that the url should be as follows:

```
GET api/values/number/house/street
```

While it looks like you call it as:

```
GET api/values/NoHouseStreet
```

So there is no slash between the values. I am guessing that if you change the url you call to the following then things should work properly:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/values/" + no + "/" + house + "/" + street);
```

Comment: I think you are correct with your first assumption, as I have tried the second and it failed :(, I will try your first solution and will mark as correct if I get it working thank you for input.

Comment: Glad it worked. But just for the sake of completeness. Was the problem the missing slashes or routing or both?

Comment: It was the routing bud, and also my lack of understating of MVC. I had to create a custom model and controller also and now I am able to request and send data perfectly. I now realise why asmx web services should be considered deprecated. MVC is great stuff.